# Getting all values of 2 columns

Tags: django, elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-query

I am looking for appropriate elasticsearch query for,

```
SELECT col1,col2 FROM myTable WHERE col1="value1" AND col2 = "value2"
```

eg:
This is my mapping,

```
{
    "mapping": {
        "doc": {
            "properties": {
                "book": {
                    "properties": {
                        "name": {
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        "price": {
                            "type": "integer"
                        },
                        "booktype": {
                            "properties": {
                                "booktype": {
                                    "type": "text"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to write a query which will give me `price` and `name` which has `booktype=Fiction`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
GET myTable/_search
{
  "size": 1000,
  "_source": [
    "price",
    "name"
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
           "match": {
             "booktype.booktype": "Fiction"
           }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Note: you might need to adapt "size" to fit your needs.

Comment: Not working with foreignkey,
In my case col1 is index.columns.col1
```
_source": {
                    "index": {
                        "columns": {
                            "col1": "Product Manager"
                        },
                        "open_positions": 2
                    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "foreignkey"?

Comment: This query works well if i am taking column that has inter, float etc(Except String).
But fails with String even after making the corresponding field searchable and aggregatable

Comment: Update your question with a sample document you want to match and your index mapping

Comment: I've updated my answer. You need to do a nested query since `tag` is nested.

Comment: Not worked,
I have made my question more precise to what i need

Comment: No errrors, But failed to get the data